# UITabBarController showing only the first tab

Tags: swift, tvos

I am reasking this because the question in [UITabbarController showing only first tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36719197/uitabbarcontroller-showing-only-first-tab) was not answered ... I don't understand why my UITabBarController is showing just the first tab .

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let tab = UITabBarController()
        let v1 = VC1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
        let v2 = VC2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)
        let v3 = VC3(nibName: "View3", bundle: nil)
        let myViews = [v1,v2,v3]
        tab.viewControllers = myViews
        self.window?.rootViewController = tab 
        return true
    }

}
```

VC1 Code:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("view 1 will load")
        self.title = "View 1"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

class VC2:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("view 2 will load")
        self.title = "View 2"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

VC3:

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("view 3 will load")
        self.title = "View 3"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

I think this is a tested and proven way to create tabs but it doesn't seem to work, here's the result screenshot

[image: Result Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a cleaner way to implement this , View Controller's title is a property and can be set right after it's instanciated

So the updated code looks like :

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let tab = UITabBarController()
        let v1 = VC1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
        let v2 = VC2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)
        let v3 = VC3(nibName: "View3", bundle: nil)
        v1.title = "View 1"
        v2.title = "View 2"
        v3.title = "View 3"
        let myViews = [v1,v2,v3]
        tab.setViewControllers(myViews, animated: false)
        self.window?.rootViewController = tab 
        return true
    }

}
```

and the screenshot is :

[image: 3 Views TabBarController]

Answer (score 3):

UITabBarController uses the `title` from each view controller to create the labels that appear on-screen. The problem here is that your view controllers don't have any value for the `title` property until `viewDidLoad` is called, which is too late.

You should be setting the `title` property during initialization; `initWithNibName:bundle:` would be a good place for this.